# Forward PTR request if not found

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ptr-record

I am attempting to find a way to forward PTR request, if not found in local master zones. I'm transitioning a network from one domain (and dns servers) to another, which is easy for A records - but a mess for PTR, as ips haven't changed.

How can I set up bind to forward PTR lookup request to another server, only if not found in the local zones (E.G 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, no. This is a common question for BIND but this software has no mechanism for that. Either it is authoritative for the zone (and have all the possible data) or it isn't (and it forwards).

Comment: To get around this, I ended up adding PTR records for all the new domain entries on the old DNS server as well